# oracle client on xpmode to access oracle 11g database fails. Where should tnsnames reside

Tags: windows-7

I have 
•a windows 7, 64-bit OS; 
•in which I have an Oracle 11g setup;
 •on top of Win 7 - XP Mode; 
•in which I have Oracle 11 client.
 I have application that needs to access the database from the xpmode.
ODBC cannnot even access the database on the windows 7.

Thanks